# Search for a patter grep in file

Tags: text-processing, grep, diff

I have the output of `diff` in the format below:

```
$ curr_dt=$(date +%m_%d_%Y)
$ echo $curr_dt
$ diff -q /POC/$curr_dt/DDL/ /POC/Backup/DDL/
Only in /POC/Backup/DDL/: comp1.txt
Only in /POC/Backup/DDL/: comp.txt
Only in /POC/Backup/DDL/: junk.txt
Files /POC/$curr_dt/DDL/test.demo_table1.txt and /POC/Backup/DDL/test.demo_table1.txt differ
Only in /POC/$curr_dt/DDL/: test.demo_table2.txt
```

I now want to get the following from the data shown above:

1. only in /POC/Backup/DDL/:
2. Only in /POC/$curr_dt/DDL/:
3. Files * differ

For example:

```
diff -q /POC/05_26_2022/DDL/ /POC/Backup/DDL/ | grep -i '^Files.*.differ$'
Files /POC/05_26_2022/DDL/test.demo_table1.txt and /POC/Backup/DDL/test.demo_table1.txt differ
```

like above, i get one full line of data. i need to get only test.demo_table1.txt from it adn save it in a file.
like wise

```
i am not able to grep with variable $curr_dt in the file
```

Comment: Hi Rose. What is it you actually want to achieve here? Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/703962/edit) to explain that.

Comment: hope i am clear

Comment: I'm afraid not, sorry. It seems like you already have exactly the output you are requesting.  Isn't the first `diff` output you show exactly what you need? If not, please [edit] your question and show us the output you would like to have.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, but please show us the _exact_ output you expect. Don't describe it, show us exactly what you need so we can know how to help you. The output of `diff` seems to have what you need already: 1) it has the line `only in /POC/Backup/DDL/:`, 2) it has the lines with  `Only in /POC/$curr_dt/DDL/:`, 3) it has the line `Files * differ` and 4) it only has txt files. So if that isn't what you need, we need to see exactly what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your `$curr_dt` varable is not set / not expanded in your code snippet given above. At least it doesn't `echo` and doesn't show up in `diff`'s output. Run your code with the `-x` (xtrace) option set.
For your other question, try

```
awk '/^Only/ {gsub("[/:]+", "_", $3); print $NF > $3} /^Files.*differ/ {sub(/^.*\//, "", $2); print $2 > "different"}' file
```

It should create three files with the respective file names in them.

On repeated request by the OP, file names reduced to the identified / identifying directory:

```
awk '
/Only/          {m = split($3, T, "[/:]+")
                 print $NF > T[m-2]
                }
/Files.*differ/ {sub(/^.*\//, "", $2)
                 print $2 > "different"
                }
' file
```

Comment: i do get the output of curr_dt.. i didnt mention that in my quest.. my bad..

Comment: can i have the filenames saved as Backup & 05_26_2022 instead of whole path with_ ?

Comment: Yes, that's easily possible in `awk`.

Comment: can you pls give teh syntax

Comment: @rose : give update a try...