# rename files based on keyword

Tags: regular-expression

i need help in renaming files:

```
$ cat q.txt
Only in /aa/bb/home/sh/POC/Backup/DDL/: comp1.txt
Only in /aa/bb/home/sh/POC/Backup/DDL/: comp.txt
Only in /aa/bb/home/sh/POC/Backup/DDL/: junk.txt
Files /aa/bb/home/sh/POC/05_26_2022/DDL/test.demo/table1.txt and /aa/bb/home/sh/POC/Backup/DDL/test.demo_table1.txt differ
Only in /aa/bb/home/sh/POC/05_26_2022/DDL: test.demo_table2.txt

$ cat q.txt | awk '/^Only/ {gsub("[/:]+","/", $3); {sub(/^.*\//, "", $3);print $NF > $3".txt"} /^Files.*differ/ {sub(/^.*\//, "", $2); print $2.txt > "different.txt"}'
```

currently it gives filename with _

```
ls -lrt
   27 May 27 07:02  _aa_bb_home_sh_POC_05_26_2022_DDL.txt
   28 May 27 07:02  _aa_bb_home_sh_POC_Backup_DDL_.txt
   27 May 27 07:04 different.txt
```

i need o/p like below

```
ls -lrt
   27 May 27 07:02  05_26_2022_DDL.txt
   28 May 27 07:02  Backup_DDL.txt
   27 May 27 07:04 different.txt
```

Comment: Is this related to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/703962/100397 ? If this other question has now been answered please accept the answer you've got there. This is how you show "thanks"

Comment: Please take a step back. What are you trying to achieve, overall? Running `diff` to then use the output for `mv` sounds overly complicated to me. There may be a better way to achieve whatever it is you really want to do

Comment: Do it in the `awk` solution given to your other question...

Comment: i am going to do diff in two sub folders and get the output stored in different files @roaima

Comment: can you pls help by providing answer @RudiC

Comment: Rose it seems you want to implement your solution using `diff` in two folders and then piping the result through `awk` to some sort of `rename`. Step back from your imagined solution a moment - what do you want to achieve?

Comment: the content from the (backup/different/05_26_2022)files will be used for further processing. for that i want only the valid names of the files instead of extra words with _

Comment: can someone help?